# Use both List View and Recycler View

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I have a List View which has layout:
list.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.phongponix.trackingbodybuilding.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <ListView android:id="@+id/lvExerciseList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingBottom="50dp"
       ></ListView>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"></View>
</RelativeLayout>
```

list_item.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="20dp">
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TableRow>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgExcercisePhoto"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp" />

                <TextView android:text="aaa"
                    android:id="@+id/tvExerciseName"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rvExcerciseRecords"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I setup CustomAdapter for ListView and it works fine.
Now i want setup Adapter for RecyclerView which will be Horizontal orientation. Something like this in my list Adapter

```
public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tracking_plan_list_item, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvExerciseName);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
            recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.rvExcerciseRecords);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(trackingPlanHorizontalAdapter);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        if (data.size() > 0) {
            ExerciseModel exercise = (ExerciseModel) data.get(i);
            viewHolder.title.setText(exercise.getTitle());
        } else {
            viewHolder.title.setText("No data");
        }

        return view;
    }
```

The problem is it will cause this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: LayoutManager android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager@48264ed is already attached to a RecyclerView: android.support.v7.widget
```

If i commented the line recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager); My recycler adapter will never execute the onCreateViewHolder or onBindViewHolder. I checked the data for this recycler already and it's not an empty array.

What should i do to have both List View with Vertical Scroll and Recycler View with Horizontal scroll in side a list item??

Comment: I am assuming reason for this issue is getview will be reused so in this case it will take the same recyclerview which is already initialized once so its throwing error

Comment: You want recyclerview inside a listview item?

Comment: Yes,  Raghavendra. I want to show a list of item with Vertical Orientation. inside each item, i want to have a another list which has Horizontal scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the linearLayoutManager from global to local, like this :

```
    public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            View view = convertView;
            if (convertView == null) {
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tracking_plan_list_item, null);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvExerciseName);
                view.setTag(viewHolder);
                recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.rvExcerciseRecords);
                LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(trackingPlanHorizontalAdapter);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }

            if (data.size() > 0) {
                ExerciseModel exercise = (ExerciseModel) data.get(i);
                viewHolder.title.setText(exercise.getTitle());
            } else {
                viewHolder.title.setText("No data");
            }

            return view;
        }
```